# PHP parse error when trying to get row from DB - Magento

Tags: php, sql, magento, zend-framework, csv

I am making script to export order details to a CSV file from a Magento webshop.

I need to get creditcard type used for payment in the CSV file. You can see current code under here.

I have commented the 4 lines that are supposed to get the creditcard type directly from table "quickpaypayment_order_status". Unfurtunately it is not working :(

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION
```

What am i doing wrong here?

```
<?php

require_once 'abstract.php';
class Mage_Shell_Export extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{

private $exportpath = 'order_export';

private $exportStatus = 'processing';

private $afterExportStatus = 'exported';

/**
 * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order
 */
private $Order;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->exportpath = $this->_getRootPath() . $this->exportpath;
    $this->Order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order;
}

public function run()
{
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->Order->getResourceCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => $this->afterExportStatus))
    ;

    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
    foreach($collection AS $order) {
        $order = $order->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());
        $lines = $this->createCsv($order);
        $this->setOrderExported($order);

        $filename = sprintf(
            '%s/%s.csv',
            $this->exportpath,
            $order->getIncrementId()
        );
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'c');
        flock($handle, LOCK_EX);
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            fputcsv($handle, $line, ';', '"');
        }
        flock($handle, LOCK_UN);
        exec('chmod 777 "' . $filename . '"');
    }



}

/**
 * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
 */
private function setOrderExported(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    $order->setStatus($this->afterExportStatus);
    $order->save();
}

private function createCsv(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    $lines = array();
    // Line 1
    // Customer labels
    $lines[] = array(
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'street1',
        'street2',
        'street3',
        'street4',
        'company',
        'zipcode',
        'city',
        'region',
        'country',
        'phonenumber',
        'mobilenumber',
        'email',
        'vat number',
        'ref number',
    );

    // Line 2
    // Billing address
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address $billing */
    $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();

    $lines[] = array(
        $billing->getData('firstname'),
        $billing->getLastname(),
        $billing->getStreet1(),
        $billing->getStreet2(),
        $billing->getStreet3(),
        $billing->getStreet4(),
        $billing->getCompany(),
        $billing->getPostcode(),
        $billing->getCity(),
        ($billing->getRegion() === null ? '' : $billing->getRegion()),
        $billing->getCountry(),
        $billing->getTelephone(),
        $billing->getFax(),
        $billing->getEmail(),
        $billing->getData('vat_id'),
        $order->getOrderreference()
    );

    // Line 3
    // Delivery address
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address $shipping */
    $shipping = $order->getShippingAddress();
    $lines[] = array(
        $shipping->getData('firstname'),
        $shipping->getLastname(),
        $shipping->getStreet1(),
        $shipping->getStreet2(),
        $shipping->getStreet3(),
        $shipping->getStreet4(),
        $shipping->getCompany(),
        $shipping->getPostcode(),
        $shipping->getCity(),
        ($shipping->getRegion() === null ? '' : $shipping->getRegion()),
        $shipping->getCountry(),
        $shipping->getTelephone(),
        $shipping->getFax(),
        $shipping->getEmail(),
        $shipping->getData('vat_id'),
        $order->getOrderreference()
    );

    // Line 4
    // Order total labels
    $lines[] = array(
        'Payment method',
        'Payment EAN',
        'Shipping method',
        'Comment',
        'Total products ordered',
        'Shipping amount',
        'Tax amount',
        'Subtotal excl tax',
        'Grand total incl tax',
        'Card type'
    );

    //  Added to fetch "Card Type" from DB
    // $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    // $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    // $table = $resource->getTableName('quickpaypayment_order_status');
    // $row = $this->paymentData = $read->fetchRow("select * from " . $table . " where ordernum = " . $this->getInfo()->getOrder()->getIncrementId());

    $ean = '';
    $cardtype = '';
    $payment = $order->getPayment()->getData('method');
    if ($payment == 'purchaseorder') {
        $ean = $order->getPayment()->getData('po_number');
    }
    if ($payment == 'quickpaypayment_payment') {
        $cardtype = $row['cardtype'];
    }

    // Line 5
    // Order total
    $lines[] = array(
        $payment,
        $ean,
        $order->getShippingMethod(),
        str_replace("\n", " ", $order->getData('customer_note')),
        $order->getTotalQtyOrdered(),
        $order->getShippingAmount(),
        $order->getTaxAmount(),
        $order->getGrandTotal() - $order->getTaxAmount(),
        $order->getGrandTotal(),
        $cardtype
    );

    // Line 6
    // Product labels
    $lines[] = array(
        'Image',
        'SKU',
        'Name',
        'Qty ordered',
        'Piece price excl tax',
        'Row total excl tax',
        'Options'
    );

    // Line 7+
    // Product info
    $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $item */
        if ($item->getParentItemId() !== null) {
            continue;
        }

        $data = array();

        $data[] = $item->getProduct()->getData('image');
        $data[] = $item->getSku();
        $data[] = $item->getName();
        $data[] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        $data[] = $item->getPrice();
        $data[] = $item->getBaseRowTotal();

        if ($item->getProductOptions()) {
            $itemoptions = $item->getProductOptions();
            if (array_key_exists('attributes_info', $itemoptions)) {
                $options = array();
                foreach ($itemoptions['attributes_info'] as $opt) {
                    $options[] = sprintf('%s:%s', $opt['label'], $opt['value']);
                }
                $data[] = implode(',', $options);
            }
        }            

        $lines[] = $data;

    }

    return $lines;
}

/**
 * Retrieve Usage Help Message
 *
 */
public function usageHelp()
{
    return <<<USAGE
Usage:  php -f export.php

USAGE;
}
}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_Export();
$shell->run();
```

Comment: Do you have the line number of the PHP error?

Comment: @CristianoCasciotti Error is caused by this: $row = $this->paymentData = $read->fetchRow("select * from " . $table . " where ordernum = " . $this->getInfo()->getOrder()->getIncrementId()); It has been commented in the code above

Comment: @user1857818 So you get a syntax error from a commented out line of code? What PHP version are you running? I get no syntax error regardless of whether those 4 lines are commented out or not.

Comment: @Jim i dont get error when i comment code, error is when i remove comment :)

Comment: @user1857818 Even with those lines included I do not get a parse error.

Comment: did you try using the solution i gave ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable $this->paymentData does not exist (not declared). if it is not a problem out of a class context, it is most probably that that brings an error.